# issue with $rootScope in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to put some value in $rootScope. So, i can get the later on other pages.  I am not sure this is the correct way or not to store the data for other pages.

Anyways, Below is the code on page 1 where i am storing the data in $rootScope. Data is stored properly. I checked in console log.

```
var ProfileApp = angular.module('App', []);

    ProfileApp.controller('getprofile', function($scope,$http,$rootScope){
                             $rootScope.pid = 'Test';
})
```

and here is the code on page 2.

```
 var ProfileApp = angular.module('App', []);

    ProfileApp.controller('getprofile', function($scope,$http,$rootScope){
  alert($rootScope.pid);
})
```

While accessing page 2 i am getting undefined as error.

Any advise what am i doing wrong or is my approach is totally wrong.

Comment: For share data between controllers use `service` or `$broadcast` and `$on` methods .

Comment: Please post the html markup for `index.html` and the two pages.

Comment: Your approach is totally wrong. Data on `$rootScope` does not persist between page reloads. If you want to use different templates in a Single Page Application, consider using a router such as [ng-route](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angularjs-routing/info) or [ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular-ui-router/info).

Comment: @georgeawg well you might be correct. I have separate pages and basically i am trying to pass data from one page to another.

Comment: @georgeawg That was a good catch. I totally missed that we were talking about two different pages.

Comment: As suggested by @georgeawg, it would be best to build both pages into angular and use a router to navigate between them.

Comment: But, if you still need both pages to be separate, you can use query parameters or local storage to pass data between the two

Comment: local storage can't work because data needs to validated whenever user using the app. Localstorage i am already using to keeping the user logged in.

Answer (score 2):

**Change 1**
Change the first line of your page 2 code to this:

`var ProfileApp = angular.module('App');`

**Explanation**

Here is the syntax for creating a module `angular.module('moduleName', [])`
Here is the syntax for getting a reference to the module already created `angular.module('moduleName')`

In your code, you were creating two different apps.

**Change 2**
Also, please use different names for your two controllers.

Comment: can you explain why is that?

Comment: getting error - Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.2/$

Comment: Added explanation. Also, you need to give different names for your controllers.

Comment: Did both changes as you suggested but still above error is coming.

Comment: Please share the html mark up of your `index.html` and both pages if you still get the error.

Comment: also this error appear - Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3. will share the markup.